# Ajax don't return response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, request, response

Hello i trying to to save response from htmlpage and save the content of this page, but i always getting an error.What i am doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    var page = "";


    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        jsonp: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            page = data;
            console.log("Good");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error");//here where i am stuck

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: "but i always getting an error" — **What error**?!

Comment: You can't set the content type of a POST message body that doesn't exist. Why do you have `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in a GET request?

Comment: Does the site actually support JSONP?

Comment: Look at the JavaScript error console and see what errors are reported there.

Comment: Read the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The **third** argument to the error function tells you the error message. Look at that.

Comment: i getting SyntaxError: syntax error  ,But it not my syntax error becuase when i open link that below the error i see the html of the requested web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html" -  i think its URL belong from other domain not from your home/base domain url.  that's why you getting error.

You can not make a AJAX http request for NON HOME url.

**NON HOME:** Its means you can only access your Base domain content though ajax.

Comment: Any suggestions what i need to do in this situation?